# minimal normal group of a finite solvable group is elementary abelian p-group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group. Suppose that $H$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then we can raise $H$ to a composition series since $G$ is finite. Since $G$ is solvable, every composition factor in the composition series is of prime order. Since $H$ is of prime order, simple and nontrivial we can say that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there any flaw in this proof?

Comment: So you are claiming every minimal normal subgroup must be $C_p$?  That doesn't work for $V\unlhd A_4$, for example.

Comment: @user10354138 would you mind mentioning which part of my proof causes this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "raise $H$ to a composition series".  If you mean $1\unlhd H\unlhd\dots\unlhd G$ then it is not guaranteed to be maximal length.  Also $H$ need not be simple, as the example shows.

Comment: You can find a composition series which will include $H$, but that does not mean that $H$ will be a composition factor!

Comment: As for the title, there are a few ways to prove it. The easiest I think is to note that a minimal normal subgroup must be characteristically simple, and such groups are direct products of simple groups.